# Android Studio Retrofit Response returned boolean as false when is sould be true

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, android-studio, retrofit

When i get object from server useing Retrofit to my android app all the values that is not booleans is accurate and all the booleans is alwase false even when the server sending them true.
If anyone has dealt with this issue before then I would be happy if I could get some help.

**i checked and the atributes as the same name
[Object boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCjUd.png)

this is response from the server inside the app debug mode
[Response from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVtwv.png)

**This is what the server tell me he send to app**

2021-05-20 14:30:53.440 DEBUG 12404 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] cloud.logic.services.DeliverymanService  : DeliverymanService GetRoute - return value: RouteBoundary(routeID=60a4d44aa63e6a30dce20968, deliverymanID=MXBkWizNBCQYUpxLfEdmy2kxAov2, deliveries=[609beaf5e8180842a0d1c62d, 609afbc00eb3232001fda466], isApproved=true, isSorted=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the issue in your `Route` class - both boolean fields are not being populated from the server response and use default values.

Probably `Gson` uses getters and setters for deserializing values, and your `Route` class has naming inconsistency for the boolean fields.

A field called `isApproved` but your setter name is `setApproved`.
Try to either:

- rename the setter following the naming pattern set%FieldName%, so it will become `setIsApproved`
- rename the field instead of `isApproved` to just `approved`

See an example below:

```
    public class Route {

        private boolean isApproved;
        private boolean isSorted;
        // OR
        private boolean approved;
        private boolean sorted;

        public Route() {
        }

        public Route(boolean isApproved, boolean isSorted) {
            setApproved(isApproved);
            setSorted(isSorted);
            // OR
            setIsApproved(isApproved);
            setIsSorted(isSorted);
        }

        public boolean isApproved() {
            return isApproved;
        }

        public void setApproved(boolean approved) {
            isApproved = approved;
        }
        //OR
        public void setIsApproved(boolean approved) {
            isApproved = approved;
        }

        public boolean isSorted() {
            return isSorted;
        }

        public void setSorted(boolean sorted) {
            isSorted = sorted;
        }
        // OR
        public void setIsSorted(boolean sorted) {
            isSorted = sorted;
        }
    }
```